# How to print text of POST request without making request

Tags: python, http-post

If I make the request

```
api-key = 'asdfklhsdfkjahsdlgkjahlkdjahfsa'
url = 'https://www.website.com'

headers = {'api-key': api-key,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

request_data = {'foo': 'bar', 'egg': 'spam'}

result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=request_data)
```

The server is contacted.  Suppose that instead I want to do something like

```
request_string = requests.foobar(url, headers=headers, data=request_data)
import os
os.system('curl ' + request_string)
```

So that I can look to see what the request is doing without bothering the server (possibly to the point that I could c&p it into `curl`), what would foobar be?  Or in general, what is a way to inspect the contents of the request without making it?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw

Comment: @holts-shoe Almost, thanks!  There are complicated solutions there but `result = requests.post(...); print(result.request)` is very useful.  The only problem there is the request seems to still be made, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869074/create-url-without-request-execution) that implies that you can use Request().prepare() to observe the request without actually sending the request.

Furthermore the [official documentation](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests)  reads "In some cases you may wish to do some extra work to the body or headers (or anything else really) before sending a request. The simple recipe for this is the following" and then it illustrates Request.prepare()